# (cocos2d-iphone) Problem-Sprite rotates 180 degree to and fro

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

hi i have a problem with sprite during startup
The problem is that the sprite rotates 180 degree to and fro once before setting to its position.
It happens very fast.
I know it is some bug but couldnt find the problem.
Can anyone please help me.
The code are as follows

```
CCSprite *arrowSprite = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Launcher2.png"] retain];
CGSize size = [arrowSprite contentSize];
arrowSprite.anchorPoint = ccp(25/size.width,20/size.height);
NSLog(@"Value of anchorPoint x,y %f, %f",arrowSprite.anchorPoint.x,arrowSprite.anchorPoint.y);
arrowSprite.position = ccp(65, 80);
[self addChild:arrowSprite z:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in your code that would cause any rotation of the sprite.  You can confirm this by reducing the posted code down to the bare bones by commenting out the line that sets the anchorPoint.  If you're still getting the rotation, it's happening somewhere else in your application.